# Can I programming directly on my cell phone? I'm using sprint touch pro 2

Tags: windows-mobile

I want to do programming directly on my cell phone. Do you guys know this kind of programming environment available? The programming language is irrelevant.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create Python apps. Google for "PythonCE" and some text editor.

Comment: Very interesting. Is MinMo actually close enough to WinCE that Wince dev tools work for it?

Comment: "PythonCE" is just a name. It's a distribution for WinMo. I use it.

Answer (score 1):

I believe you are probably referring to the HTC Touch Pro 2:

[image]
<sub>(source: [cellphonestalk.com](http://www.cellphonestalk.com/wp-content/uploads/2009/08/htc-touch-pro2-smartphone-3.jpg))</sub>

This is a Windows Mobile - based phone, so to develop software for it you'll need to get a WinMo dev kit, which can be [downloaded here](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyID=06111A3A-A651-4745-88EF-3D48091A390B&displaylang=en). You will have to buy yourself a copy of Visual Studio (2005 or later), but it looks like all the other dev tools can be downloaded for no cost.

Comment: Looks like the OP is looking for a windows mobile based IDE, not an SDK that targets windows mobile.

Comment: Admittedly, it looks that way, but that's a rediculous question (although it would be an interesting research project for a grad student). I'm answering what he probably actually wants, or at least what *can* be done. Sometimes when English isn't folk's first language, it helps communications when you meet them halfway rather than get all technical on what their words precisely mean.

Comment: ...then again, I could be totally wrong. Wouldn't be the first time.